# Error "WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire" in android studio

Tags: android, crash, wakelock

my app is crashing and I get this error in my logcat :

```
04-11 23:50:51.278 2294-26973/? E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a 
matched acquire!
04-11 23:50:51.317 2294-4859/? E/ExecutionCriteria: Package unavailable 
 for task: com.viber.voip/.schedule.ViberGcmTaskService{u=0 
tag="json_stickers" 
trigger=window{period=28800s,flex=3600s, 
earliest=-51214144s,latest=-51210544s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] 
attributes=[PERSISTED,RECURRING] scheduled=-51239344s last_run=N/A jid=N/A 
status=PENDING retries=0 client_lib=MANCHEGO_GCM-10400000}
04-11 23:50:51.318 2294-4859/? E/ExecutionCriteria: Package unavailable 
for task: com.viber.voip/.schedule.ViberGcmTaskService{u=0 
tag="apps_info_sync" 
trigger=window{period=86400s,flex=21600s, 
earliest=-51174544s,latest=-51152944s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] 
attributes=[PERSISTED,RECURRING] scheduled=-51239344s last_run=N/A jid=N/A 
status=PENDING retries=0 client_lib=MANCHEGO_GCM-10400000}
04-11 23:50:51.318 2294-4859/? E/ExecutionCriteria: Package unavailable 
for task: com.viber.voip/.schedule.ViberGcmTaskService{u=0 
tag="json_engagement_stickers" 
trigger=window{period=86400s,flex=8640s, 
earliest=-51161584s,latest=-51152944s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] 
attributes=[PERSISTED,RECURRING] scheduled=-51239344s last_run=N/A jid=N/A 
status=PENDING retries=0 client_lib=MANCHEGO_GCM-10400000}
04-11 23:50:51.319 2294-4859/? E/ExecutionCriteria: Package unavailable 
for 
task: com.viber.voip/.schedule.ViberGcmTaskService{u=0 
tag="json_say_hi_engagement_config" 
trigger=window{period=86400s,flex=8640s, 
earliest=-51161584s,latest=-51152944s} requirements=[NET_CONNECTED] 
attributes=[PERSISTED,RECURRING] scheduled=-51239344s last_run=N/A jid=N/A 
status=PENDING retries=0 client_lib=MANCHEGO_GCM-10400000}
```

If it is relevant, I am using an NTP server and an AlarmManager,  What can be the reason behind this error ? and how to solve it ?